Is the 2nd law a reason for the irreversibility of natural processes or a consequence of it?
I have been introduced to chemical engineering thermodynamics due to my academic background. I had learnt about internal energy, entropy etc and applied the equations to various scenarios of practical importance eg, calculating how efficient a thermal power plant is? Recently I read principles of chemical equilibrium by Kenneth Denbigh which consequently lead me to skim through the mechanical theory of heat by clausius. This exposed the fundamental difference in the way concepts were introduced in academia and in this texts.
For example, concept of entropy was first introduced in academia along with equations and then applied to prove that heat can't flow from lower to higher temperatures. Whereas these texts consider the later fact as an axiom and then through propositions and proofs led to 2nd law. Which left an impression that 2nd law is not the reason for irreversibility of natural processes but the consequence of it.
So, is entropy just a function to describe the nature and has no say on the cause behind the observations about irreversibility of natural processes? If so then how the popular description of entropy as measure disorder is related to idea of entropy as transformation- defined so by clausius in his book?(additionally is take of academia in this  matter also prevalent in other parts of world?)

The first part of this book is a thorough, and very accessible explanation of the second law: https://www.amazon.com/Cycles-Time-Extraordinary-View-Universe/dp/0307278468/ (But beware! The book dives into deep controversy shortly afterward. Read the rest of it at your own risk.)

"...mechanical theory of heat by clausius." If you prefer to read primary sources rather than "accessible" interpretations,
then read Boltzmann's work on statistical mechanics.

"For example, concept of entropy was first introduced in academia along with equations and then applied to prove that heat can't flow from lower to higher temperatures.". I think this is backwards. That heat can't flow naturally from lower to higher temperatures is a fact of observation. The problem is it didn't violate the first law (conservation of energy), necessitating the identification of a second law that would be violated.


So, is entropy just a function to describe the nature and has no say on the cause behind the observations about irreversibility of natural processes?

That's right. Entropy is a concept, a function of macrostate. It is not cause of anything. You don't have to use this concept to formulate 2nd law.
Irreversibility of natural processes is a characteristic of this world that we obtained via observations and experiments, and some of this characteristic is captured by 2nd law of thermodynamics (what isn't captured by 2nd law is speed of the irreversible processes).
The ultimate cause of irreversibility is not something physicists agree on. Some regard it as due to special initial condition of the world, because all the basic equations are time-symmetric, and boundary conditions aren't. This is the easiest viewpoint to understand and adopt.
Others see it as the most probable evolution of things, regardless of the initial condition (e.g. the fluctuation hypothesis), and others as property of the fundamental laws themselves (Prigogine?), even though we do not know them yet. These other viewpoints are, I think, a minority.

If so then how the popular description of entropy as measure disorder is related to idea of entropy as transformation- defined so by clausius in his book?(additionally is take of academia in this matter also prevalent in other parts of world?)

Not sure what you mean by "take of academia". There is the Clausius entropy, defined by $S(X_2) = \int_{X_1}^{X_2} dQ/T$, which is usually what is meant by "thermodynamic entropy" in all textbooks on thermodynamics or physical chemistry.
Clausius started with an assumption that heat flows from higher to lower temperature can't happen spontaneously, and for any cyclic process, derived the Clausius inequality
$$
\oint \frac{dQ}{T_r} \leq 0,
$$
where $T_r$ is temperature of the environment of the system(thermal reservoirs). The cyclic process does not have to be reversible.
A special case of this is the equation for reversible cyclic processes
$$
\oint \frac{dQ}{T} = 0,
$$
where $T$ is temperature of the system. This has also been called the theorem of equivalence of transformations. Surprisingly, this equation is what Clausius claimed the Second law in his theory was[1]. But we don't call it 2nd law today; we call it a special case of the Clausius inequality for reversible cyclic processes.
See the paper
[1] Xue, T.-W.; Guo, Z.-Y. What Is the Real Clausius Statement of the Second Law of Thermodynamics? Entropy 2019, 21, 926. https://doi.org/10.3390/e21100926
Clausius wrote further things about entropy which are questionable, such as formulation of 2nd law in terms of entropy of Universe.
Thus what Clausius wrote about 2nd law and entropy is important and interesting for history of physics and of thermodynamics in particular, but is not entirely how we understand 2nd law and thermodynamic entropy today.
